Calculating Pr(X>Y) using Probability Integral Transform if X, Y are iid continuous
Calculate $Pr(X>Y)$ given X and Y are unknown r.v. that are iid continuous.
The above problem can be solved intuitively since X and Y are iid continuous. However I was wondering if I can also solve this using Probability Integral Transform theorem.
Here is my working/thinking:
$Pr(X>Y)= Pr(Y<X)=F_Y (X)$
Its given that X and Y are identical. Thus, $F_Y (X) = F_Y (Y)$
Now, if I truly understand the Probability Integral Transform, $F_Y (Y)$ follows a uniform distribution $U ~ (0,1)$
Similarly, since X and Y are identical, if $F_Y (Y)$ is uniform then $F_Y (X)$ is also uniform
So my thinking is to construct a joint cdf $Pr(X>Y)$ defined on the interval $0<y<x<1$
This gives:
$$ Pr(X>Y)=\int_0^1 \int_0^x F_Y (X)F_Y (Y) dydx=\int_0^1 \int_0^x 
 dydx = \frac{1}{2}$$
Is this a right approach?

It is not correct that $\mathbb{P}(Y<X) = F_Y(X)$. In particular $F_Y(X)$ is random while the probability is not.

@raj but I thought if we can represent $Pr (X<x)$ as $F_X (x)$ then we should be able to represent $Pr (X<y)$ as $F_X (y)$ and $Pr (X<Y)$ as $F_X (Y)$? May be I am totally misunderstanding the underlying concept behind the symbols. How about if I represent $Pr (X<Y)$ as $F_{XY} (Y)$ , is that right?

You need to apply the law of total probability, as done below :
$$
\Bbb{P}(Y < X) = \int_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{P}(Y < X \,|\, X = x) \,\mathrm{d}F_X(x) 
               = \int_\Bbb{R} F_Y(x)f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x 
$$
In the case of two iid random variables, this expression can be simplified further :
$$
\Bbb{P}(Y < X) = \int_\Bbb{R} F(x)f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x 
               = \left[\frac{1}{2}F(x)^2\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 
               = \frac{1}{2}
$$
This result is somewhat unsurprising, because a situation where a random variable would "dominate" another variable, while being both identically distributed, would constitute a paradox.

Addendum.
As mentioned by Raj in his comment, the expression $F_Y(X)$ couldn't be compared to $\Bbb{P}(Y < X)$ directly, for the reason that it is a random quantity, when the latter is a probability. Nevertheless, they are related to each other through $\Bbb{P}(Y < X) = \Bbb{E}[F_Y(X)]$.

I get it now. Thanks a lot!

@Obinoscopy. I'm glad to help ;) You may accept my answer for future people looking for an answer to the same problem.
